# Upload PlugIn Button is missing

Tags: plugins, uploads, buttons

I want to upload a zip file but there is no option for uploading, the button is missing..[image]

Comment: is this a multisite install? Or a managed host with a git repo? Or wp.com? I notice there's a report issue button in your admin toolbar? Keep in mind this stack is for developer questions rather than user support, you may be asked to provide code or be given code as an answer

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by a plugin (Elementor maybe?), because the title of the page is not showing. Try turning off your plugins to see if the title shows.

If you want to go directly to the upload plugin try to add `url.com/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=upload`.